# POD is not getting mapped to service if deployed through yaml configuration

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy the container using yaml.
The POD is getting created but service is not getting mapped to POD. What I am missing here?

Be informed I am using trial subscription on Google Cloud and kubernetes-SDK on my machine.

**Deployment file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: udemydocker1
  name: udemydocker
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 30
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: udemydocker1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: udemydocker1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: lazyav/udemydocker:Release.1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: udemydocker
      restartPolicy: Always
      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: udemydocker1
  name: udemydocker
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: udemydocker
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**Dashboard screen shot and command line commands**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue is due to selector **app: udemydocker**. The service was unable to find the POD.
Changing it to **app=udemydocker1** solves the problem

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: udemydocker1
  name: udemydocker
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: udemydocker1
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 0):

In service:
selector:
app: udemydocker1

In deployment:
spec:
progressDeadlineSeconds: 30
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: udemydocker1